# KeyBindingApi. Enter doesnt know

Tags: java, enter

I tried to do an Action, when pressing Enter on a Button.

```
        System.out.println(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ENTER").getKeyCode());
        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ESCAPE"),"esc");
        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released ESCAPE"),"esc released");

        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ENTER"),"enter");
        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released ENTER"),"enter released");
```

I don`t know why, but
the sysout got 10, so the inputmap knows the keystroke with the String ENTER, but If I take it in lieke here it doesnt work. ESCAPE works perfectly, but ENTER didnt work. If I cast this to char and making

```
        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke((char) KeyEvent.VK_ENTER),"enter");
        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released ENTER"),"enter released");
```

Then it works. But I tjink this is ugly and I dont want to cast this, because usually "Enter" should work I think.

Comment: Please read [MCVE]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, and this is heavy documented, `KeyListener` is unreliable.

In order for `KeyListener` to work, the component it is registered to MUST be focusable AND have keyboard focus.

Adding components like `JButton` move the keyboard focus away from your component and give it to the other components instead, so `KeyListener` stops working.

There are any number of "work arounds", but frankly, they are unreliable and are essentially just hacks.

You're better off using the [Key Bindings API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) which solves the short comings of `KeyListener` and provides a much more re-usable and flexible API

Comment: mhhh I tryed. See my answer below